# Replace SonicWall NetExtender VPN client with a non-commercial / standard Linux solution?

Tags: vpn, software-rec

I currently have to use [SonicWall NetExtender](https://www.sonicwall.com/products/remote-access/vpn-clients/) to remote VPN into my work (Windows 10) machine, however I'm fairly convinced it's not doing anything that couldn't be replicated with free/open software on my Linux host machine (currently Mint 20).

Does anyone have any experience on this sort of thing / suggestions of software known to work?

I don't have any admin control over the work end of things, so any solution has to work with things as they are.